# Strain relief fitting for a 1-1/2 inch sch 40 pvc type c conduit body?

Tags: electrical, wiring, junction-box

I am running power from my main panel in my basement to a sub-panel in my attached garage.  At some point I need to transition from the 2-2-2-4 SER aluminum cable being run perpendicular through my unfinished basement ceiling joists into pvc conduit that feeds up into the sub-panel.  While my SER cable was still horizontal, I was going to use a sch 40 pvc type c conduit body for the transition.  What kind of strain relief fitting should I look for where the SER cable enters the conduit body through the non-threaded port?  Or should I use something else at the end of the conduit stub to make the transition instead of the type c conduit body?

Comment: I take it here that the conduit length is simply being used to shield the cable from mechanical damage?

Comment: Yes, just from the basement cable run through the wall and up to the bottom of the subpanel.

Answer (score 1):

### The correct fitting for this job is a *bell end*

When using PVC conduit to protect an adequately supported cable from mechanical damage, the fitting you want to use at the end isn't a conduit body, but a *bell end* fitting of the appropriate size for your conduit.  This provides a clean terminus for your conduit that protects the cable from being abraded on its edge.

Comment: So something that clamps around the SER cable as a strain relief where it enters the conduit isn't needed?

Comment: @user149104 -- as far as I can tell, it is not -- do let me know if your local AHJ disagrees, I'd like to know what Code section they're pointing at to require it!